# Linux system mails alternative for sending and receiving besides SMTP

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, email, system-monitoring

I have multiple EC2 servers which run either Ubuntu or Amazon Linux. I want to run automatic system updates but get a message when the system is updated. The `yum-cron` package can send emails, but I do not want to host an email server. Especially that outgoing SMTP messages are blocked in AWS by default.

Is there an alternative way to receive these messages in AWS? Maybe send all messages to SNS, Elasticsearch or Systems Manager? How can it be configured? How is this managed on a large scale in a data centre?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Configure your preferred log system to forward logs to wherever you desire, and configure cron to *not* send e-mails?

Comment: Configure postfix to receive email locally and forward it to your email address. As for stopping cron sending emails, I have the same problem, haven't worked out how to stop it yet.

Comment: @vidarlo what are the tools to achieve this? Could I write them to CloudWatch logs easily? How to differentiate the severity?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can have a local mail system which sends all the locally generated mail to a configured *smarthost*, some remote mailer which is supposed to do all the hard work. You don't need a full-blown local mailer like Postfix for that, use a rudimentary MTA like `ssmtp` or similar. Typically you submit mail to the smarthost using authenticated SMTP submission service on port 587 or 465, so it wouldn't be blocked by AWS.
2. If you don't want to see them as e-mails at all, this requires a bit more work. One way to achieve this is to *receive* all the generated mail and forward it to a pipe on the local system, and the program which listens to a pipe can apply any other way of processing them. For instance, with Postfix that is possible with `|command` alias target like `|/usr/local/bin/mail-processor.sh`, see more about it in the [`aliases` manual page](https://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html). Or, you can use a [`pipe` transport](https://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html).
3. All the events which are reported using mail also are reported into local logs. So you can just *discard* all the cron-generated mail altogether (for example, make a command alias which accepts mails and does nothing), and only forward *logs* to whatever log collector you prefer to use, for example, to ELK.

Comment: that's a nice answer. I think 1 and 3 are feasible solutions for me. Please extend your answer with specific tool recommendations for both parts, or other "keywords" for me going down the two rabbit holes. Maybe for 3 something like fluent bit?

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic on ServerFault. Keywords are alredy there: "ssmtp", "ELK".